# Vue.js and Jest - Element-UI how to programmatically confirm MessageBox?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, element-ui

I'm currently creating tests with Jest and I would like to know how to programatically confirm ElementUI's MessageBox because I can't seem to get it's HTML DOM. So that it would execute my graphql queries inside `then()`. I really don't know if this is a good practice or not since I'm new at Jest.

```js
confirmBox(
        this,
        'warning',
        'Delete Record',
        'Do you really want to delete this record?',
        true
      ).then(() => {
        this.loading = true

        deleteGame(id, (response, success) => {
          if (success) {
            this.$message({
              message: 'Record successfully deleted',
              type: 'success'
            })
            this.get()
          } else {
            this.$message({
              message: response,
              dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
              type: 'error'
            })
            this.loading = false
          }
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Element-ui has unit test for all there components, however they are written in karma.

They seem to trigger the Ok button as follows:

```
it('confirm', done => {
    MessageBox.confirm('This is a piece of content', {
      title: 'Title name',
      type: 'warning'
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector('.el-message-box__wrapper')
        .querySelector('.el-button--primary').click();
      expect(document.querySelector('.el-message-box__wrapper')
        .__vue__.$parent.visible).to.false;
      done();
    }, 200);
  });
```

Full source: https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/test/unit/specs/message-box.spec.js